# Magento - specific mobile / desktop Menu

Tags: menu, rwd, mobile

I have found a lot of different ways to make the mobile menu different from the desktop one, but I'd like to use the same menu, but in different sequence. Is it possible at all in Magento?

e.g. I have **1. Home, 2. Cart, 3. Account** in desktop view, but when it changes to mobile menu, the same list should be: **1. Cart, 2. Home, 3. Account**.

I didn't find any guide to this specific question. Any Idea? :/